# How to make SQL server return last rows first in select not using order by

Tags: sql

I have a table with 350 000 rows. When I search top 50 I get the 50 oldest rows. Is there any way to make SQL server to start from the bottom so I get the last 50 rows that bin inserted?

We have some performance issue so I can't use any syntax that loop through all records.

If I add the order by Id it takes 14 sec instead of 1 sec. I use Dynamic SQL to solve the search functionality for dynamic table structure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [CS.Core].[spDynamicSearchInsuranceDemoCar] @ChassisNumber AS NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
    ,@FirstOwner AS BIT = NULL
    ,@GroupId AS INT = NULL
    ,@InsuranceNumber AS INT = NULL
    ,@InsuredId AS INT = NULL
    ,@Model AS NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
    ,@OwnerYearOfBirth AS INT = NULL
    ,@RegistrationNumber AS NVARCHAR(12) = NULL
    ,@StakeholderId AS INT = NULL
    ,@StatusId AS INT = NULL
    ,@UserId AS INT
    ,@LanguageId AS INT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@paramlist NVARCHAR(4000)

    SELECT @sql = 'SELECT TOP 50 Insurance.InsuranceId,
ISNULL(ProductCaption.CaptionText, [CS.Core].Entity.Name) AS
Product_462, Stakeholder.RefStakeholderName AS Stakeholder_1093,
Insurance.ValidFrom as ValidFrom_925, Insurance.InsuranceNumber,
Insurance.GroupId, Insurance.StatusId, Insurance.ValidFrom,
DemoCar.RegistrationNumber, DemoCar.Year, DemoCar.ChassisNumber,
DemoCar.FirstOwner, DemoCar.Model  From [CS.Entity].Insurance INNER
JOIN [CS.Core].Entity on Insurance.EntityId = Entity.EntityId  LEFT
JOIN [CS.Entity].Stakeholder ON Insurance.StakeholderId =
Stakeholder.StakeholderId LEFT JOIN [CS.Core].Caption AS
ProductCaption ON (ProductCaption.CaptionCode = Entity.TextId AND
ProductCaption.LanguageID = @LanguageId)  INNER JOIN
[CS.Entity].[DemoCar] ON [CS.Entity].[DemoCar].[RootId] =
[CS.Entity].[Insurance].[InsuranceId]  WHERE
[CS.Entity].Insurance.GroupId in (Select SecGroupID from
[CS.Security].SecRelation Where SecUserID = @UserId)'

    IF @ChassisNumber IS NOT NULL
        IF CHARINDEX('%', @ChassisNumber) 0
            SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND ([CS.Entity].[DemoCar].[ChassisNumber] 
Like @ChassisNumber)'
        ELSE
            SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND
([CS.Entity].[DemoCar].[ChassisNumber]  = @ChassisNumber)'

    IF @FirstOwner IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND
([CS.Entity].[DemoCar].[FirstOwner]  = @FirstOwner)'

    IF @GroupId IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND
([CS.Entity].[Insurance].[GroupId]  = @GroupId)'

    IF @InsuranceNumber IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND
([CS.Entity].[Insurance].[InsuranceNumber]  = @InsuranceNumber)'

    IF @InsuredId IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND
([CS.Entity].[Insurance].[InsuredId]  = @InsuredId)'

    IF @Model IS NOT NULL
        IF CHARINDEX('%', @Model) 0
            SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND
([CS.Entity].[DemoCar].[Model]  Like @Model)'
        ELSE
            SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND ([CS.Entity].[DemoCar].[Model]  = @Model)'

    IF @OwnerYearOfBirth IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND
([CS.Entity].[DemoCar].[Year]  = @OwnerYearOfBirth)'

    IF @RegistrationNumber IS NOT NULL
        IF CHARINDEX('%', @RegistrationNumber) 0
            SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND ([CS.Entity].[DemoCar].[RegistrationNumber]  Like
@RegistrationNumber)'
        ELSE
            SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND
([CS.Entity].[DemoCar].[RegistrationNumber]  = @RegistrationNumber)'

    IF @StakeholderId IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND
([CS.Entity].[Insurance].[StakeholderId]  = @StakeholderId)'

    IF @StatusId IS NOT NULL
        SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND
([CS.Entity].[Insurance].[StatusId]  = @StatusId)'

    SELECT @sql = @sql + ''

    SELECT @paramlist = '@ChassisNumber AS NVARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
@FirstOwner AS BIT = NULL,  @GroupId AS INT = NULL,  @InsuranceNumber
AS INT = NULL,  @InsuredId AS INT = NULL,  @Model AS NVARCHAR(50) =
NULL,  @OwnerYearOfBirth AS INT = NULL,  @RegistrationNumber AS
NVARCHAR(12) = NULL,  @StakeholderId AS INT = NULL,  @StatusId AS INT
= NULL,  @UserId as int, @LanguageId as int'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
        ,@paramlist
        ,@ChassisNumber
        ,@FirstOwner
        ,@GroupId
        ,@InsuranceNumber
        ,@InsuredId
        ,@Model
        ,@OwnerYearOfBirth
        ,@RegistrationNumber
        ,@StakeholderId
        ,@StatusId
        ,@UserId
        ,@LanguageId
END
```

Comment: Use an index to improve performance

Comment: If you don't specify an `ORDER BY`, you'll get 50 random rows; unless you specify a `ORDER BY`, there's no guarantee of any ordering and ordering might change between calls to the query...

Comment: Performance issues when using `ORDER BY` indicate a lack of appropriate index.  If you want to search out a specific set of 50 records (the 50 most recently inserted) you should ensure that you have the appropriate index to complete that search/ordering.

Comment: "My eyes" yes the sp is generated by C# code dynamically. When I pasted it all my NewLine was lost.

Answer (score 5):

> *"When i search top 50 i get the 50 oldest rows."*

No, you get 50 rows. Period. 50 rows that your DBMS chooses to return. 50 more or less random rows.

If you want the 50 rows that were inserted last, you'll have to have a column that stores such information (InsertionDateTime). Then index it. Then you can run:

```
SELECT TOP (50)
    * 
FROM 
    mytable 
ORDER BY
    InsertionDateTime DESC ;
```

Comment: +1. What was I thinking!! It does return in clustered index order most of the time, but there is no guarantee.

Comment: @Diego: He asked "not using order by" and he explained in the question that he has performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an IDENTITY primary key column, then you can order by that column descending (because that's the order rows are inserted, and the id is monotonically increasing)

```
SELECT TOP 50 *  
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY IdentityColId DESC
```

**Note**: the fact SQL Server by default creates the clustered index on a table's Identity primary key column is not sufficient to guarantee ordering.

Comment: There are a few (admittedly rare) cases where `IDENTITY` does not coincide with insertion time.

Comment: haven't seen one yet, and there would have to be 50 such instances for the above query to be wrong,, but I take your point. And isn't this fixed in 2012?

Answer (score 1):

considering you have a IDENTITY ID column

```
select * 
from YOUR_TABLE
where id > (select max(id) from YOUR_TABLE) - 50
```

EDIT:

If you don't have an ID, you will need to do something with row_number but them you will need an order

Comment: And what about missing IDs?  Due to failed inserts, or deletes.  Also, if `ORDER BY id` causes performance problems, this will hit ***exactly*** the same performance problems.  The OP's desire to not use `ORDER BY` is an indication of a lack of appropriate INDEX.  To make this solution performant requires the same fix as making `ORDER BY` performant; appropriate indexing.

Comment: This may not return 50 rows but less. Even just 1 row. And the `ID` is not always related to insertion time.

Comment: @ypercube, how exactly a IDENTITY ID wont be related with insertion time?

Comment: @Dems, missing ids wont be returned because they dont exist. Not sure what you meant here...This query will always return the last 50 rows inserted.

Comment: @diego - No, it *won't* always return the last 50 rows.  Imagine a new table is created, 100 rows inserted, then rows 51 to 99 are deleted.  Your query will return 1 row; row 100.

Comment: @Diego: various cases: 1.You can set [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) and choose the IDs, not let SQL-Server do that.

Comment: you're right, point taken. Not a good solution when it involves delete. I actually use it to query log table, which data is never deleted

Comment: @ypercube - To be fair to Diego on the `does a higher id equate to a more recently inserted record?` question; Using `IDENTITY_INSERT` is the same as altering *(falsifying)* the `InsertionDateTime` value in your answer.  Without external interference to the identity mechanism or values, the only time it's not true is when multiple records are inserted together.  So `a record with a greater id can not have been inserted -before- a record with a lower id` seems a perfectly reasonable assertion.

Comment: @Dems: Yeah, you have a point (about falsifying). But there are other cases, too. Like having an `IDENTITY(-1,-1)` definition. (Yeah, I know it's not common at all). Or an `IDENTITY(12345678, 1000000019)`.

Comment: And there would be probably be cases with Replication and partitioned (over the Identity) tables.

Comment: Hi if I add the order by Id it takes 14 sec instead of 1 sec. I use Dynamic SQL to solve the search functionality for dynamic table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Add an "ORDER BY insertime DESC" (or whatever your yardstick for "old" is, sequential ID etc.)
on the end of your select. But yes, also check that you have decent indices set up. Use explain plan if you're not sure.